# What is the purpose of the header element 'x-instagram-ajax' in API calls via Python to Instagram?

Tags: python, python-3.x, instagram, instagram-api

On the instagram login page, if one inspects the element of the POST call for the url 'https://www.instagram.com/accounts/web_create_ajax/', it lists the following as headers:

```
Host: www.instagram.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.13; rv:61.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/61.0
Accept: */*
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Referer: https://www.instagram.com/
X-CSRFToken: 7dmO9F3JuVGvSXumd79yByPxnHoWHz1A
X-Instagram-AJAX: c2d8f4380025
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
Content-Length: 102
Cookie: csrftoken=7dmO9F3JuVGvSXumd79yByPxnHoWHz1A; mid=W30zsQAEAAErXHJ3iUojfTceCd53; mcd=3; csrftoken=7dmO9F3JuVGvSXumd79yByPxnHoWHz1A; rur=FTW
Connection: keep-alive
```

I am wondering if anyone would have any idea what `X-Instagram-AJAX` is and how I can generate it each time. Is it connected as a pair with `X-CSRFToken`? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Follow, like etc requests working without this header. I don't know what is it but i think instagram dedects suspicious requests with this and then log it. You can get this value on any page in instagram [This is x-instagram-ajax value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rb98y.png)

You can parse it and use.

Comment: Why do you think that Instagram uses it to detect suspicious requests? As in, is it an account-wide identifier, like the user ID? https://stackoverflow.com/q/76434810/9731176